# Sort polars dataframe by indices in column

Tags: python, python-polars

Say I have:

```py
df = pl.from_repr("""\
shape: (4, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬──────┐
│ idx ┆ a   ┆ b   ┆ idx2 │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
│ u32 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ u32  │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪══════╡
│ 0   ┆ 1   ┆ 4   ┆ 3    │
│ 2   ┆ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ 0    │
│ 3   ┆ 2   ┆ 1   ┆ 2    │
│ 4   ┆ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 4    │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴──────┘
""")
```

I would like to sort it so that column 'idx' respect is in the order given by 'idx2'.

Desired output:

```py
shape: (4, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬──────┐
│ idx ┆ a   ┆ b   ┆ idx2 │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
│ u32 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ u32  │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪══════╡
│ 3   ┆ 2   ┆ 1   ┆ 2    │
│ 0   ┆ 1   ┆ 4   ┆ 3    │
│ 2   ┆ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ 0    │
│ 4   ┆ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 4    │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴──────┘
```

How can I do this, in a way which will work in both lazy and eager mode?

Comment: The basic idea is to make a new column containing the index of each element of `idx2` in `idx`, so `[2, 1, 0, 3]` then sort by that new column.

Comment: yup. but...how?

Comment: Is this not answered by your other question? `df.select(pl.all().sort_by(pl.arg_sort_by("idx2", "idx")))`

Answer (score 0):

```py
indices = {v: i for (i,v) in enumerate(df.get_column("idx"))}

df.lazy()
    .with_columns(pl.col("idx2").apply(lambda n: indices[n]).alias("sort"))
    .sort("sort")
    .collect()
```

```
shape: (4, 5)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬──────┬──────┐
│ idx ┆ a   ┆ b   ┆ idx2 ┆ sort │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ u32 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ u32  ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 3   ┆ 2   ┆ 1   ┆ 2    ┆ 0    │
│ 0   ┆ 1   ┆ 4   ┆ 3    ┆ 1    │
│ 2   ┆ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ 0    ┆ 2    │
│ 4   ┆ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 4    ┆ 3    │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴──────┴──────┘
```

Comment: thanks - this works, but `get_column` isn't available in lazy mode

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work although I'm not sure if it is guaranteed to work in all cases. Essentially it's just a self join

```
df=df.lazy()
df.join(df.select('idx2'), left_on='idx', right_on='idx2').collect()
shape: (4, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬──────┐
│ idx ┆ a   ┆ b   ┆ idx2 │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
│ u32 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ u32  │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪══════╡
│ 3   ┆ 2   ┆ 1   ┆ 2    │
│ 0   ┆ 1   ┆ 4   ┆ 3    │
│ 2   ┆ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ 0    │
│ 4   ┆ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 4    │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴──────┘
```